# How do I restrict qBittorrent from all wifi networks but one?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, qbittorrent

I want to set up automatic downloading via an RSS feed. Before I do that, I need to make sure qBittorrent can't run on any other network than the one at home. This is because I'm absolutely sure I will mess up sometime and be in the wrong place on the wrong network when qBittorrent starts up and starts downloading stuff while I'm not paying attention.

I'm aware of the Network Interface option, but it seems to only let me choose between different types of networks, and not a specific one.

Any way I can set it to only work on the home network? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably better to remove it from the startup apps. Then you start it only when and where you want. What you want doesn't exist, isn't a feature.

Comment: Is there really no way to have qBittorrent check which network I'm on, or have another program restrict qBittorrent when on the wrong network?

There can't just be a problem like this with no solution, can there? It seems like such a simple thing.